# After integrating to existing project, how to handle an unexpected error

Tags: android, ios, migration, integration, react-native

After integrating React Native to existing project, how to handle some unexpected error in iOS and Android native code?

For example, Network is unreachable or some error from React Native view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well at least for a network error (assuming you are using the FETCH api), you can add a 'catch' and show an alert/do something else:

```
fetch('/some/url', {
  method: 'get'
}).then(function(response) {

}).catch(function(err) {
  // Error :(
});
```

Comment: it need to connet nodejs server for every time, what to do if raise some error from the OC code?

Comment: Errors which are raised from objective C should probably be handles using objective C error handling tools.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i still have a question. When the nodejs server is unreachable or some other error state, RTCRootView show the error state immediately show error reason on red screen.I don't want show this message to user. What to do with this?

Comment: Once your app is deployed (even on testflight), red-screen style errors won't appear, your app will just crash. Not sure if that's the answer you are looking for.